# Make an enhanced for loop wait until something is done

Tags: java, for-loop

I am creating a Black Jack game. I'm at the point where if an Ace shows up, it'll ask the user if the Ace should be low or high.

```
    for(Card card : hand){
        ui.choseAce = false;
        if(card.getPointValue() == 1){//If it is an ace.
            ui.lowOrHigh();//Preps UI to ask if ace is low or high
        } else{
            if(hand.equals(playersHand)){
                playerPointTotal += card.getPointValue();
            } else{
                dealerPointTotal += card.getPointValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

In a separate class...

```
public void lowOrHigh(){
    hitButton.setVisible(false);
    standButton.setVisible(false);
    lowButton.setVisible(true);
    highButton.setVisible(true);
    updateUI(buttonPanel);
    inputJTFLabel.setText("Is your ACE low or high?");
}
```

And then the buttons...

```
    if(obj.equals(lowButton)){
        choseAce = true;
        Game.playerPointTotal += 1;
    }

    if(obj.equals(highButton)){
        choseAce = true;
        Game.playerPointTotal += 11;
    }
```

I tried adding a while loop into the lowOrHigh() method...

```
while(!choseAce){}
```

But when an ace appears it just freezes. I also tried putting a similar while loop into the enhanced for loop. Just freezes.

I'd like to have the enhanced for loop wait until either the highButton or lowButton is pressed and then continue back where it left off without having to save loop positions, etc.

Edit: If I prompted a JOptionPane question would that pause the for loop until the JOPtionPane has been answered?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I'd rather not do JOptionPane as it would break the flow of my GUI.  Would prefer to keep everything consistent.

Comment: If you are using Swing, it might be a good idea to put that in the label list.